# Null foreign key, in ManyToOne relation using hibernate [4.1.1] annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am trying to persist a one-to-many and a many-to-one relation using *Hibernate 4.1.1* but the foreign key is always *NULL*.

There are two entities: *Account* and *Client*. A *Client* could have multiple *Accounts* while an *Account* has exactly one *Client*.

Here are the classes (only what matters):

**Account.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private Client client;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client")
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private List<Account> accounts;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
session.beginTransaction();

Client client = new Client();
Account account1 = new Account();
Account account2 = new Account();

a.addAccount(account1);
a.addAccount(account2);

session.save(client);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

While running, Hibernate adds the foreign key to the table:

`Hibernate: alter table account add index FKB9D38A2D3B988D48 (id_client), add constraint FKB9D38A2D3B988D48 foreign key (id_client) references client (id)`

Both accounts have id_client column *NULL*.

I tried putting **nullable = false** at the @JoinColumn relation but that just invoked an exception.

`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'id_client' cannot be null`

Comment: Try adding the @NotNull annotation on the account side of the relation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot to add the client to the accounts.

```
account1.setClient(client);
account2.setClient(client);
```

Now it works. Thank you for the tips. ;)

Comment: Four hours wasted discovering that I needed to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: you really saved my life... i was going to bang my head to the wall

Comment: I thought that this is done automatically, it fix  Column 'id_client' cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is that you need to save account first and in the last client will be saved.